# How do you print time series description above?

Tags: r

I'm writing a function and I would like it to work similar to ts from base r. After creating an object and printing it I would like my custom text to be printed above actual data.

This is how it works for ts()

```
values = cumsum(rnorm(6))
my_ts <- ts(values, start=c(2012,1))
my_ts

Time Series:
Start = 2012 
End = 2017 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -1.932780 -2.429412 -3.534139 -2.674516 -4.417406 -5.546133
```

This is what I want to change:

```
Time Series:
The first year listed= 2012 
The last year listed = 2017 
Frequency = 1 
[1] -1.932780 -2.429412 -3.534139 -2.674516 -4.417406 -5.546133
```

I am wondering how do you get this description i.e.:
I can't straightforward copy it from ts, because I want to change a few things. I looked everywhere and did not find anything.

Comment: The code you have shows you creating a time series _object_. This is completely different from creating your own time series _class_

Comment: I edited my question, it was a little bit confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to create an S3 class. You can do it like this:

```r
timeseries <- function(x, start, frequency = 1)
{
  if(length(start) > 1 | !is.numeric(start) | any(is.na(start))) 
    stop("'start' must be a single number")

  times <- seq(start, by = 1/frequency, length.out = length(x))
  structure(list(values = x, times = times, freq = frequency), class = "timeseries")
}

# Define a print method:
print.timeseries <- function(x){
  cat("timeseries:\n")
  cat("First year:", x$times[1], "\n")
  cat("Frequency:", x$freq, "\n")
  cat("Last year:", x$times[length(x$times)], '\n')
  print(x$values)
}
```

So now you can do:

```
 timeseries(1:7, 2012, frequency = 2)
#> timeseries:
#> First year: 2012 
#> Frequency: 2 
#> Last year: 2015 
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not at all sure that this is what the question is asking for but it does create an object `y` of a new class, class `"custom"`.

```
as.ts.custom <- function(x, start, ...){
  if(!inherits(x, "ts")){
    x <- ts(x, start = start, ...)
  }
  class(x) <- c("custom", class(x))
  x
}
as.custom <- function(x, ...){
  class(x) <- "custom"
  as.ts(x, ...)
}
print.custom <- function(x){
  Tsp <- tsp(x)
  cat("Custom Time Series:\n")
  cat("First year:", Tsp[1], "\n")
  cat("Frequency:", Tsp[3], "\n")
  cat("Last year:", Tsp[2], '\n')
  as.numeric(x)
}
values = cumsum(rnorm(6))

y <- as.custom(values, start = c(2012,1))
class(y)
print(y)
#Custom Time Series:
#First year: 2012 
#Frequency: 1 
#Last year: 2017 
#[1]  0.9085011  0.4034415  0.1024375 -0.6235985 -1.8036755
#[6] -1.5506008
```